# Laravel 5.3 taking 1.9 seconds with single SQL query and caching employed

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel, optimization

I'm working on a Laravel 5.3.30 app that is performing unacceptably slow, and it seems like there is some issue beyond what any level of optimization can solve. I'm developing the app on the following environment:

Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit including PHP 7, MySQL 5.7.14, and Apache 2.4.23
Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
ORM: Doctrine 2
Hardware: ZBook 17 G2, i7-4710MQ Processor, 8gb Memory, Quadro K2200M, SSD

I've read about Laravel performance and the advice seems to be to not pay too much attention to speed as the ample performance of production servers will handle the bloat of the framework as I plan to put it on a VPS server running on SSD drives. But my hardware itself isn't all that slow and is also running on SSD, so I'm not so sure. I feel that there is something fundamentally wrong with the setup and have attached the below results from debugbar for loading a very basic page which calls a single SQL query (for selecting the user to verify the session), along with the full SQL log with "general-log" enabled for the request.

[image: debugbar results]

[image: full query log]

I've run the usual optimizations with minimal effect:

- php artisan optimize --force
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan route:cache
- php artisan clear-compiled
- caching

I've seen many posts with people stating that achieving <100ms for basic requests on Laravel 5 like the one I benchmarked for this post is a non-issue, so I assume there is something else that's going on here, and I'm hoping someone can point me to what is causing this slow down.

Thanks!

**Update**

It just occurred to me as soon as I posted this, that I'm using a symlink inside the webroot to connect to the public folder in the Laravel app (which is outside the webroot), and I wonder if this symlink is what is causing the slowdown? I will update if I get the chance to benchmark this.

**Update 2**

As per the suggestion to test the speed for an Ajax request, the results from the debugbar below show it's just as slow, if not slower.

[image]

Comment: are you using `ORM: Doctrine 2` instead default eloquent ORM????, what if you just make a ajax call to a route which does not have any view just return JSON data. I mean create an REST endpoint to get or insert data into DB, call that REST endpoint using any browser or POSTMAN and see the speed. I am getting my data processed and return result in <200 ms

Comment: Yup, I'm using Doctrine 2 instead of Eloquent, will try the Ajax and report back in a few.

Comment: best combination i think using its default ORM but not sure, I will see the performance if i use doctrine. but yeah create one end point and make call to that end point and see the speed in console.

Comment: Just updated the question with the results of the Ajax request; it's just as slow.

Comment: What did you do with the ajax call?? and did you call any database oriented job or just make call to a plain php method???

Comment: It's an autocomplete script, which is meant to run fast anyway, and it gets the data from cache on the server side.

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.

Comment: Thanks, the SQL is available in the 2nd image, but I've just answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

So having used PHP's get_included_files(), it turns out that Laravel was including some 700 files, and I thought this was the culprit. But having asked a couple of folks on slack, they had similar include numbers, so I realized that I was caching wrong. First off, I should have been calling the optimize query after calling the config cache query, as per:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan optimize --force
```

And sure enough, this reduced the number of files being included to under 500 files. And as per advice from slack, I took the remaining files and cached as many of them as possible using obcache, which helped as well. So now it's running at acceptable performance, and I imagine using a more fine-tuned strategy with obcache would speed things up even more.